# Gallery is not opening

Tags: audio, gallery, google-photos

I have multiple issues in my android device and I believe all are related to Gallery.

- Gallery is not opening.
- No images in Google Photo.
- When I go to File Manager > DCIM > Camera, I see all images. If I open any of these image files, it gives me an option to opens files with Google Photo.
- Phone is not in silent/ vibration mode. However, phone doesn't ring for any incoming calls and alarm.
- I open media players like Music, MX Player, etc; I don't see any audio file in any location. But I can play audio files, if I go to File Manager.

I did..

- Reboot device multiple times
- Removed and reinserted battery and
- Did Clear Data and Clear Cache for Gallery

However, issues not fixed.

I don't want to reset my android device. Can these issues be fixed without doing reset?

Please guide me. How to fix it?

EinfoMail

Comment: What device do you have, what software version is it and model number? Some manufacturers allow you to install/uninstall updates for some of the stock apps from their own markets which can fix some of these issues. When multiple issues arise it's usually caused by an unstable software update but can't tell without info.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone has malwares that hide files by adding a `.nomedia` file in every folder, and such folder should not be scanned and indexed by multimedia players.

Download ES Explorer, go to its settings and enable *Show hidden files*. Afterwards browse to every location where your photos, videos, music are stored and you should see a .nomedia file, delete it. Your files should now appear.